# Is there an simple function to count and output several column values together in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have an application connected to a database. Now I want to add the values from several columns of several datasets together

I tried with the SUM()-Function but i don't know how to spend the values so that they are visible in the application.

I have no idea how to build the code smart.

it should be like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(column1)+(column2)";
```

echo $Sum of all columns and datasets.

Comment: Hi @Fernando, can you show how your output should look like?

Comment: Here is an example of what it should look like:

Database
ID, apples, bananas, tomatoes

Dataset 1: (1, 2, 3, 1,)

Dataset 2: (2, 1, 3, 2)

Now I want to use PHP/MySQL to calculate the sum of all apples, bananas and tomatoes. In this case the sum should be =12 (3x apples, 6x bananas and 3x tomatoes).

You know what I mean?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
I have now following code:

 $sql = " SELECT
   SUM(ps_asyl_oberteil) as 'ps_asyl_oberteil',
   SUM(ps_asyl_unterteil) as 'ps_asyl_unterteil',
   SUM(ps_asyl_jacke) as 'ps_asyl_jacke',
   (SUM(ps_asyl_oberteil) + SUM(ps_asyl_unterteil) + SUM(ps_asyl_jacke)) as 'Total'
  FROM ps_asyl";

  Line 20: echo $result->Total;
```

and I receive the following error message:

Notice: Undefined variable: result in /opt/lampp/htdocs/lab/asylanten_detail.php on line 20

Notice: Trying to get property 'Total' of non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/lab/asylanten_detail.php on line 20

Comment: You can't accept question as an answer

Answer (score 0):

It is easy:

```sql
SELECT 
   (column1 + column2 + column3) as 'Total'
FROM table;
```

Or if you want to output as one row:

```sql
SELECT 
   SUM(column1) as 'column1',
   SUM(column2) as 'column2',
   SUM(column3) as 'column3',
   (SUM(column1) + SUM(column2) + SUM(column3)) as 'Total'
FROM table;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thank you for your answer!

So how do I output it as a echo?

Comment: Well, once you execute the query, it will give the following result object:
echo $result->column1; echo $result->column2; echo $result->column3; echo $result->Total; It depends if you use a framework or raw php.

Comment: Show your code what have you tried.

Comment: the answer below

Comment: How do you execute the query? and the variable `$result` is undefined. The query execution should be assigned to a variable i.e `$result` and then you would be able to use `$result->Total`